# Selecting rows with pandas.loc using multiple boolean filters in sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
stuff = [
    {"num": 4, "id": None},
    {"num": 3, "id": "stuff"},
    {"num": 6, "id": None},
    {"num": 8, "id": "other_stuff"},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
```

I need to select rows where "num" is higher than a given number but only if "id" is not None:

This doesn't have any effect:

```
df = df.loc[df["num"] >= 5 & ~pd.isnull(df["id"])]
```

What I need is something like this (presudocode):

```
df = df.loc[
    if ~pd.isnull(df["id"]):
       if df["num"] >= 5:
          select row
]
```

The expected result:

```
>>> df
    id        num
 1  stuff       3
 2  None        6
 3  other_stuff 8
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use `df = df[(df["num"] >= 5) & (df["id"].notnull())]`

Comment: @jezrael that doesn't work, it returns the last row only. The boolean checks should be sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parantheses (because priority operators) with `|` for bitwise `OR` instead `&` for bitwise `AND`, also for inverted `pd.isnull` is possible use `notna` or `notnull` for oldier pandas versions:

```
df = df[(df["num"] >= 5) | (df["id"].notna())]
print (df)
   num           id
1    3        stuff
2    6         None
3    8  other_stuff
```